# elegant (i.e., non-hard-coded) way to position `UITextField`, `UITextView`, and `UIButton` relative to each other?

Tags: ios, position, positioning

I have the following screen in my app.

[image: screen image]

Right now the positioning is all hard-coded, and it's not pretty. It's one textview with several `\n`s in the middle and a textfield and button carefully positioned, experimenting pixel by pixel, and then hard-coded in, which is fine except then if I switch to a 4-inch screen it's useless.  Plus it's just ugly.

I've been looking around stackoverflow trying to find answers, and I found some things about creating a `CGPoint` at a specific `UITextPosition`, but unfortunately I'm too much a novice to understand the answers.

Is there an elegant way to soft-code these positions relative to each other?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**  Here's the positioning code:

```
    if (!optOut) {
    optOut = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 95, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20, 200);
    optOut.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    optOut.text = @"\n\n\nI hope to update the Haiku app periodically with new haiku, and, if you'll allow me, I'd like permission to include your haiku in future updates.  If you're okay with my doing so, please enter your name here so I can give you credit.\n\n\n\nIf you DON'T want your haiku included \nin future updates (which would make \nme sad), check this box.";
}
[self.view addSubview:optOut];
if (!checkboxButton) {
    checkboxButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    checkboxButton.frame = CGRectMake(236, 260, 44, 44);
    [self.view addSubview:checkboxButton];
}
[textView resignFirstResponder];
if (!nameField)
{
    nameField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 223, 240, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:nameField];
}
```

Instead of placing `optOut` at `(20, 95, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20, 200)`, I'd like to be able to put it at (say) `(20, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2-100, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20, 200)`.  But if I do that--if the starting position of `optOut` moves depending on how tall the screen is--then I have to move `nameField` and `checkBox` too, and I don't know how to keep them in the same position relative to `optOut`.

Comment: Do you have some of the positioning code? Also what do you mean hard coded? Have you tried the interface builder and then linking the methods?

Comment: Edited question to add code and clarification.  I've tried using Interface Builder but I must be doing something wrong--perhaps I don't understand AutoLayout--because when I use different screen sizes everything gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, I would put the second part of that UITextView (after all the returns) into its own object and tack it on to the view by itself.  And then the simplest way to go about this with what you have is to ask the elements directly for frame placement, so where you have

```
checkboxButton.frame = CGRectMake(236, 260, 44, 44);
```

do something like (and I apologize I if the syntax is a bit off but you can get the idea)

```
checkboxButton.frame = CGRectMake([optOut center].y + pixelsToMoveOverToWhereYouLikeIt, [optOut center].y + pixelsToMoveDownToWhereYouLikeIt , 44, 44);
```

And so on for the others.  That would make all the view either relative to each other or to one the first textview, depending on which object you reference.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to break it apart into different components that you can position individually, and either use constraints to automatically position them or move them individually in code.  Also, a `UILabel` would be better to display the static text, since you don't need the user to be able to edit the text.  Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't see this until after I'd fixed the problem using @Jeremy 's answer, so I had to give him credit, but this is very helpful and I'll definitely switch the `UITextView`s to labels.  (I was setting their `editable` property to `NO` but labels makes more sense.)  Thank you!'

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways you could do this. The first is to use auto-layout. I don't have any experience with auto-layout because it is an iOS 6+ feature, but it would probably be worth learning.

The way I usually do it would be be something like:

```
view1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200);
view2.frame = CGRectOffset(view1.frame, 0, 20); // same as view1, offset down 20 points
view3.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(view2.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view2.frame)+10, 80, 80);
```

These `CGGeometry` helper functions are quite useful. There are more obscure `CGGeometry` functions that are less useful, but can be great in some situations: http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/ For the full list, just check out the `CGGeometry` documentation

Comment: These are really helpful--I didn't know about them.  I've fixed the code as per @Jeremy 's answer, but this will help me make it even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The text field looks indeed ugly there. You want an UITextField of type `custom` with a nice self styled image as backgound. That way you can postion the text as you want. Do the same with the button of type `custom`, use 4 different images for the 4 states (unchecked, unchecked-pressed, checked and checked-pressed).